# Run GraphQL Mutation using Apollo Client

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo

So I have this GraphQL Mutation which allows a user to create an account:

```
mutation {
  register(input: {
    email: "bob@gmail.com"
    password: "bob123"
  }) {
    user {
      id
      email
    }
    errors {
      path
      message
    }
  }
}
```

And I want to run this mutation using Apollo Client (Note: I am using TypeScript)

```
const REGISTER: DocumentNode = gql`
mutation Register($type: String!) {
  register(input: {
    email: $type
    password: $type
  }) {
    email
    id
  }
}
`
```

```
<form onSubmit={(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    register({ variables: { input: {email: emailValue, password: passwordValue} } })
}}>
```

And I keep running into this error:
[image: error img]

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: passed variable (`input`) different to defined in query/mutation (`type`) - read docs https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables ... and test mutation in playground using "query variables"

Comment: Thanks I already figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: I fixed it by doing this:

```
// GraphQL Mutation to register an account
const REGISTER: DocumentNode = gql`
mutation register($email: String!, $password: String!) {
  register(input: {
    email: $email
    password: $password
  }) {
    user {
      email
      id
    }
    errors {
      path
      message
    }
  }
}
`
```

Comment: usually shorter [and better] is to use `$input: someInputType` variable (read type from API) and pass it to query by `register(input: $input)`